# ursa with node 6.0.0 Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 47

Tags: node.js, express, module

I was able to get 0.9.3 installed with Node 6.0.0.
Running on OSX (10.11.4)

When I add `require('ursa')` and run the project it throws.
Any idea what could be causing this error?

```
....../node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83 throw e ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 47.
  at Error (native)
  at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
  at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:466:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at bindings (/Users/xxxxx/Documents/MyProjects/projectName/bc-ui/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
  at Object (/Users/xxxxx/Documents/MyProjects/projectName/bc-ui/node_modules/ursa/lib/ursa.js:18:37)
  at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
```

Comment: You've omitted the first line of the error, but I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584529/module-version-mismatch-expected-11-got-1)