# Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 48, node

Tags: node.js, npm, require

When I require the following file modules

```
const nodejieba = require('nodejieba');
```

I found a error in console. The following error was reported in the console:

```
 module.js:435
 return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                ^
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 46, got 48.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:435:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
 (/home/electronDesktopTool/node_modules/nodejieba/index.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
 Process finished with exit code 1
```

In my package.json file, The nodejieba version is `"nodejieba": "^2.2.4",` ,and When I used `npm i nodejieba --save-dev`, there was no error

I have tried to delete the `node_modules` folder and `npm i`, but I still haven't solved it, and I have tried `npm rebuild` without solving it. Please tell me who else has encountered it

Comment: How did you installed nodejieba ? What was version installed ?

Comment: I use npm install nodejieba, The version is "nodejieba": "^2.2.4"

Comment: Try with some other version of nodejieba, we faced same issue with some version when switched to older it worked.

Comment: Then what version do you use

Comment: I do not remember exactly which version it was, but you can try with 2.0 or 2.1

Comment: Still not, I try 1.4.11-2.2.5 all the versions, it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module version mismatch. Expected 11, got 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584529/module-version-mismatch-expected-11-got-1)

Comment: what is your node version? try version 8 lts